# Multiindex from array in Pandas with non unique data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
In[45]: data[:10]  
Out[45]:
   Z    A    beta2    M      shell
0  100  200  0.3112   197.2 -4.213
1  100  200 -0.4197   202   -1.143
2  100  200  0.03205  203    0    
3  100  201  0.2967   191   -4.434
4  100  201 -0.4893   196.1 -4.691
5  100  202  0.3084   183.4 -4.134
6  100  202 -0.4873   188.2 -4.75 
7  100  202 -0.2483   188.4 -1.106
8  100  203  0.3069   177.1 -4.355
9  101  203 -0.4956   182.5 -5.217
```

My question is, how can I group/transform the data in such a way that I have a MultiIndex with (Z,A) as indexes(or MultiIndexes) having into account that the data is not unique? To clear my goal this is what I expect to achieve:

```
             beta2[1] beta2[2]  beta2[3]   M[1]   M[2]   M[3]   shell[1]   shell[2]  shell[3]
   Z    A 
0  100  200  0.3112   -0.4197   0.03205    197.2  202    203    -4.213     -1.143    0
1  100  201  0.2967   0.4893    NaN        191    196.1  NaN    -4.434     -4.691    NaN
2  100  202  0.3084   -0.4873   NaN        183.4  188.2  NaN    -4.134     -4.75     NaN
3  100  203  0.3069   NaN       NaN        177.1  NaN    NaN    -4.355     NaN       NaN 
4  101  203  -0.4956  NaN       NaN        182.5  NaN    NaN    -5.217     NaN       NaN
```

I understand that this involves at least two steps, one for the uniqueness and one for the indexing in Z,A so any help in one of those steps is appreciated, also, is there some data structure which is maybe more appropiate for this problem?

Edit: I have found that the line:

> data=data.set_index(('Z','A'))

solves the the problem of the indexing in Z,A. Unfortunately this only works if (Z,A) pairs are unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have an open issue to work on problems like these:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/388

Here is a solution. First a simple (and not very efficient) function to get the group ordinal number:

```
def group_position(*args):
    """
    Get group position
    """
    from collections import defaultdict
    table = defaultdict(int)

    result = []
    for tup in zip(*args):
        result.append(table[tup])
        table[tup] += 1

    return np.array(result)
```

i.e.

```
In [49]: group_position(df['Z'], df['A'])
Out[49]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0])
```

Now use this as an auxiliary index variable and unstack:

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]: 
     Z    A    beta2      M  shell
0  100  200  0.31120  197.2 -4.213
1  100  200 -0.41970  202.0 -1.143
2  100  200  0.03205  203.0  0.000
3  100  201  0.29670  191.0 -4.434
4  100  201 -0.48930  196.1 -4.691
5  100  202  0.30840  183.4 -4.134
6  100  202 -0.48730  188.2 -4.750
7  100  202 -0.24830  188.4 -1.106
8  100  203  0.30690  177.1 -4.355
9  101  203 -0.49560  182.5 -5.217

In [53]: df['pos'] = group_position(df['Z'], df['A'])

In [54]: df.set_index(['Z', 'A', 'pos']).unstack('pos')
Out[54]: 
          beta2                       M                shell              
pos           0       1        2      0      1      2      0      1      2
Z   A                                                                     
100 200  0.3112 -0.4197  0.03205  197.2  202.0  203.0 -4.213 -1.143  0.000
    201  0.2967 -0.4893      NaN  191.0  196.1    NaN -4.434 -4.691    NaN
    202  0.3084 -0.4873 -0.24830  183.4  188.2  188.4 -4.134 -4.750 -1.106
    203  0.3069     NaN      NaN  177.1    NaN    NaN -4.355    NaN    NaN
101 203 -0.4956     NaN      NaN  182.5    NaN    NaN -5.217    NaN    NaN
```

Final munging to get it exactly like you showed:

```
In [61]: result = df.set_index(['Z', 'A', 'pos']).unstack('pos')

In [62]: result.rename(columns=lambda x: '%s[%d]' % (x[0], x[1]+1)).reset_index()
Out[62]: 
     Z    A  beta2[1]  beta2[2]  beta2[3]   M[1]   M[2]   M[3]  shell[1]  shell[2]  shell[3]
0  100  200    0.3112   -0.4197   0.03205  197.2  202.0  203.0    -4.213    -1.143     0.000
1  100  201    0.2967   -0.4893       NaN  191.0  196.1    NaN    -4.434    -4.691       NaN
2  100  202    0.3084   -0.4873  -0.24830  183.4  188.2  188.4    -4.134    -4.750    -1.106
3  100  203    0.3069       NaN       NaN  177.1    NaN    NaN    -4.355       NaN       NaN
4  101  203   -0.4956       NaN       NaN  182.5    NaN    NaN    -5.217       NaN       NaN
```